# How can I add new icon label for category in menu?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, menu, labels

I need to display label like new, hot sale, offer for the category in the menu. How can I do that?

Comment: You can add this by custom class in menu tab and add css in them

Comment: @Sheenu : am just new, could you pls explain briefly

Comment: You have to add css in menu and call gif image in that css

Comment: @Sheenu : could you pls give me a demo

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to add new category attribute, example: **customlabel**

[How to add new custom category attribute](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-new-custom-category-attribute-in-magento/)

And you can modify this PHTML to show your custom attribute

```
app\design\frontend\base\template\page\html\topmenu\renderer.phtml
```

Comment: @ Ryan Permana : There is no file, app\design\frontend\base\template\page\html\topmenu\renderer.phtml, after : app\design\frontend\base  there is no template folder.

Comment: @Rathinam : sorry my bad, it's in rwd template app\design\frontend\rwd\enterprise\template\page\html\topmenu\renderer.phtml

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add new category attribute (e.g. customlabel)

[How to add new custom category attribute](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-new-custom-category-attribute-in-magento/)

And you can replace with this phtml to show your custom attribute

File path: **app\design\frontend\base\template\page\html\topmenu\renderer.phtml**

```
<?php
$html = '';

$children = $menuTree->getChildren();
$parentLevel = $menuTree->getLevel();
$childLevel = is_null($parentLevel) ? 0 : $parentLevel + 1;

$counter = 1;
$childrenCount = $children->count();

$parentPositionClass = $menuTree->getPositionClass();
$itemPositionClassPrefix = $parentPositionClass ? $parentPositionClass . '-' : 'nav-';

foreach ($children as $child) {
    $_id = $child->getId();
    $_id_parts = explode('-', $_id);
    $_is_hot=false;
    $_is_new=false;
    if($_id_parts[0]=='category'){
        $id = end($_id_parts);
        $categoryModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        $category= $categoryModel->load($id);
        $_is_hot = $category->getIsHot();
        $hoteClass=(isset($_is_hot) && ($_is_hot==1))?'<span class="hotactive">Hot!</span>':'';
        $newClass=(isset($_is_new) && ($_is_new==1))?'<span class="newactive">New!</span>':'';
    }

    $child->setLevel($childLevel);
    $child->setIsFirst($counter == 1);
    $child->setIsLast($counter == $childrenCount);
    $child->setPositionClass($itemPositionClassPrefix . $counter);

    $outermostClassCode = 'level'. $childLevel;
    $_hasChildren = ($child->hasChildren()) ? 'has-children' : '';

    $html .= '<li '. $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) .'>';

    $html .= '<a href="'. $child->getUrl() .'" class="'. $outermostClassCode .' '. $_hasChildren .'">'. $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName())) .$hoteClass.$newClass.'</a>';

    if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) {
        $html .= '<div class="'. $childrenWrapClass .'">'; 
    }

    $nextChildLevel = $childLevel + 1;

    if (!empty($_hasChildren)) {
        $html .= '<ul class="level'. $childLevel . '">';
        $html .=     '<li class="level'. $nextChildLevel . '">';
        $html .=         '<a class="level'. $nextChildLevel . '" href="'. $child->getUrl() .'">';
        //$html .=             $this->__('View All ') . $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName()));
        $html .=             $this->__('View All ');
        $html .=         '</a>';
        $html .=     '</li>';
        $html .=     $this->render($child, $childrenWrapClass);
        $html .= '</ul>';
    }

    if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) {
        $html .= '</div>';
    }

    $html .= '</li>';

    $counter++;
}
return $html;
```

Please manage CSS for use.